# PhpStorm SCSS file-watcher creates duplicates

Tags: css, sass, phpstorm

I recently added a SCSS file-watcher in PhpStorm and generally it does what it is suppose to. The only issue I have is that it creates a new folder within the sass-folder everytime it synchronizes. The new folder doesn't have a name but it includes the files of the sass-folder.

These are the settings of the file watcher:
[image]

Scope: 
The sass-folder

Arguments: 
`--style expanded --no-cache --update $FileName$:../css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`

Output paths to refresh:
`../css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:.../css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map`

Is there something wrong with the settings?

Comment: There are 3 dots in the output path. change it to: `../css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:../css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map`

Comment: *"The new folder doesn't have a name but it includes the files of the sass-folder."* Please clarify this part. In any case: at quick glance your file watcher seems to be setup correctly and most likely that "copy" thing must be done by something else. P.S. Unrelated to the problem ... but I personally use [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) ([ruby one](https://sass-lang.com/ruby-sass) is now end-of-life, Sass site recommends using [Dart-sass](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass) now). Node and Dart one use diff parameters so check them first if you plan to use it.

Comment: @Refilon Thank you for the info. I have changed the output path. I am not sure whether that fixed it or now. All I can say for sure is that the folders without name are still there. If I add any changes to the folders they will also be taken over to all of the other folders. Do you have any Idea why this is happening like that? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you very much for your response. The folders do not have a name but they contain the same files as the original folder.
I know that the ruby version is deprecated. I will eventually move to either dart or node.

Comment: @Refilon the issue with the three dots definitely has fixed the issue. I deleted one of the folders. After which all of them were gone. When I then reverted everything it only showed the one folder so that worked. Thank you so much again. Do you want to post this as a real answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. I created it as an answer, so that future visitors can see the answer directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 dots in the output path. Change it to:

```
../css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:../css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map
```